# Services to host images online?

Tags: webapp-rec

all I need is a simple service that allows me to host images online and have access to the direct URL of the image (without paying and without obtrusive ads).

http://imageshack.us does not give me direct URL of the image.
http://www.freeimagehosting.net has way too many ads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://imgur.com will do the job for you. You can upload an image from your computer or from the web and it will provide you with a direct link.  You can even group multiple images in to a group.

Sign up isn't required but if you do it's pretty easy and it lets you manage your images and image groups etc.

[image]

imgur is [used by Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) when uploading images to questions and answers

Answer (score 1):

http://www.photobucket.com has direct links for free.

For example: http://i51.photobucket.com/albums/f351/charonn0/sad-eyes-dog-1.png

Comment: but i'm forced to signup..

Comment: Yes. And? You didn't specify that you didn't want to have to sign up.